# Extending monitor power supply DC cable

Tags: display, power-supply, cable

I have 3 LG monitors mounted on my desk.

Two of those are barely reachable by the DC power cable: it is only 1.2m long and I need at least 50cm more for it to fit in my cable management system. So at the moment those power blocks are just dangling from the desk.

Extending the AC cable part of the adapter is not an option: the actual block has to stay under the desk.

I can't find a suitable replacement adapter for my 2 screens, so I thought about extending the DC cable by +/- 50cm.

I've seen some posts here and there about the voltage dropoff when extending a DC cable, but those posts were mainly about extending the cables by a few meters, not 50cm.

I'm also worried about any noise it might generate in the signal.

So is there anything I should keep in mind when doing this?

And about the actual extending itself: if it can be done, do I need to solder the cables or can I use something like a screw-terminal block?

[image: Power block with 20AWG cable of 1.2m length]

Comment: Why not to stop by at any hardware store and get simple short AC extension cord and velcro fasteners? Extend it with extension cord  and to keep it under the table just put in on velcro under the table. As about extending DC, Im pretty sure, nothing bad would happened, just use the same or bigger wire gauge if AC extension cord won't work 4 u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to solder the wires together and then put shrink tubing around them as shown in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATioUXpC05w

But it is probably sufficient to just twist the wires together without soldering as this video demonstrates

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8_s1xr_p9Q

But try not to use extremely thin wire.

Comment: Also, leave the RF choke attached to the plug, so that it's close to the monitor, since from the photo, it looks like the monitor is the concern (a switching power supply also produces RF, but the choke is closer to the monitor).

Answer (score 1):

You can buy DC cable extenders, or could just buy a longer AC cable for the AC end of the power brick and attach the brick to something solid (like the monitor bracket?) , so that it doesn't dangle.

Answer (score 1):

couldnt you just make the thinner cable longer using 12 volt power extension cord?  Here is a link of one on amazon.  i am looking to do this too, so if anyone advises against it, please let me know.
[12 volt power extension cord - male to female](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K58LF9Q)